# Databinding in ASP.NET User Control

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, user-controls, webforms

What is the best way to create a data bound ASP.NET user control?

I  have a user control that contains a drop down list and three label controls. I would like to data bind the drop down list, and have the label controls display different properties of the data source.

I have Googled for an example of IDataSource and User Control, but cannot find any good information. This must be a common use of a user control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward approach is to add Bind(*data*) method to user control that delegates *data* to inner controls and do whatever you want. For example implementation may set DropDownList.DataSource property and then call DropDownList.DataBind...
This approach may be used from any webpage processing stage (page_load, page_init, another control event handler...) and gives clear workflow to me. You always know when data is bound.

Another option is to override [DataBind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5e5992d.aspx) method and rely on standard asp.net webpage processing workflow.